# Filename filter based on multiple conditions

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code to return files in the directory where the extension is ".mp4".

I want to adapt the code so that it returns files which have .mp4 extension but do not contain the string "temp" in the rest of the filename

```
final String[] vids = dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(".mp4");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return name.endsWith(".mp4") && !name.contains("temp");
```

Comment: urgh hadnt thought of that :o